# Sending AngularJS form to NodeMailer to send email

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, email, nodemailer

I have a built an email form in a modal instance using AngularJS that contains the field sending email, recipient email, subject, and email content. The form uses input boxes and ng-models to keep track of the data. When the user hits the send button on this form, I would like to send all of the information collected by the models to the server to send an email.

Currently, I have a draft button and when the user hits the draft button, I send all of the information collected in the models to a controller who sends it to a service so that I can repopulate the information if the user decides to close the modal instance and send the email later. However, if the user hits the send button, I have this object with all of the information but don't know how to send it to the server. I'm very new to node.js and backend in general so if you someone could provide a concrete short example for me to learn from that would be great.

I'm looking to use the nodemailer module which I have installed using npm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the node side you can create a REST end point in order to recieve a POST request from the server for the form submission of email in the modal box. The REST end-point will look like this if you have an express server.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
app.post('/postEmail',function(req,res){
    //Your NodeMailer logic comes here
});
```

In the angular part, just like you have written a service, you can create an angular factory to invoke this REST end point.

For example:

```
myApp.factory('postEmailForm',['$http',function($http){
   return {
     postEmail: function(emailData,callback){
       $http.post("/postEmail/", emailData).success(callback);  
     }
   }
}]);
```

where myApp is your angular module, emailData is the emailForm data which you want to send to the server (it will be posted in the body of the request)

Comment: could you explain the callback component of the function you've written?

Comment: callback is used inorder to make the controller wait for the data (a success msg in this case) from the server. That will be the res.send what ever you decide to send

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm trying to implement this part but it keeps telling `POST http://localhost:9000/postEmail/ 404 (Not Found) `

Comment: have you set an endpoint with /postEmail at the server end?just like what i have in the answer?

Comment: yes, I placed that in my libs folder where the rest of my node code is

Comment: yes you need to add that...and try adding a console.log on the server and see if your end point gets hit

Comment: the only difference is that I combined the service I had and the service your wrote above

Comment: I'm trying to add `app.route("/postEmail")` to my routes folder but it doesnt make a difference

Comment: you need to have app.post

Comment: so just app.post('/postEmail')?

Comment: I see that and i have included those two pieces of code in the approrpiate places. However, when I try to run I still get the Ok thank you, I'm trying to implement this part but it keeps telling POST http://localhost:9000/postEmail/ 404 (Not Found) which is why I'm wondering if I still need to include something in the routes.js folder...if so what must I include here. I've been messing around with this code for a while now and cant get the POST to be successful from the angularJS service

Comment: Where u r creating the server

Comment: You can come up with a plunkr so that i can see ur server code and check where u making the miatake

Comment: the problem was I had to restart my server after making changes. stupid mistake..thx for the help

Comment: Hey one quick question...right now this works perfectly...but the postEmail gets called again after like a minute with duplicate information. I suspect its because I haven't ended with res.end() but when I try including this I get undefined is not a function. Any ideas?

Comment: need to check your code..can you post a different question giving an insight to the code that you have write now like the rest end point as well as the route function you might be calling so that i can have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Angular code:

```
angular.module('sendmailApp', [])
.controller('MailController', function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.send = function (mail){
        $scope.loading = true;
        $http.post('/sendemail', {
            to: mail.to,
            subject: 'Message from AngularCode',
            text: mail.message
        }).then(res=>{
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.serverMessage = 'Email sent successfully';
        });
    }

})
```

Node.js code:

```
let express = require('express'),
app = express(),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
nodemailer = require("nodemailer"),
server = require('http').Server(app);

const OTP_EMAIL_CONFIG= {     
"host": 'smtp.gmail.com',     
"port": 465,     
"secure": true,     
"auth": {         
"user": 'enter gmail account',         
"pass": 'gmail password...'     
} };

let mailModule = nodemailer.createTransport(OTP_EMAIL_CONFIG);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send('hello world!');
}) // Method to send email....
app.post('/sendemail',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body,'request');
     var mailOptions = {
        from: '"jsonworld " enter gmail account which you want to use for sending email',         
to: req.body.to,         
subject: "mail sending with angularjs and nodejs",  
       text: "Congratulations! mail is sending properly now."     
};     
mailModule.sendMail(mailOptions);     
res.status(200).send('Mail sent successfully'); })
server.listen(3003,function(){ console.log('server listening on port: 3003'); });
```

For getting working demo [go here](https://jsonworld.com/demo/Send-email-using-angularjs-and-nodejs-nodemailer-module)