# Adapt Nodemailer as a REST service for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, nodemailer

I have been struggling with the logic client/server side to adapt the Nodemailer component https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer to my angular project. 
Ihe only source i have seen close from what i want to do is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614635/sending-angularjs-form-to-nodemailer-to-send-email) from V31. 
But i am not sure how to create an "end point server side" as it is explained in the post and the user did not share his code ^^

What i want is to create an angular service for the nodemailer logic and be able to call it for a specific controller that will have my data to send.

Do i need express server to use nodemailer? in the Nodemailer-master the file `full.js` is capable of sending email on her own

```
'use strict';

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Create a SMTP transporter object
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'myemail',
        pass: 'mypass'
    }
});

console.log('SMTP Configured');

// Message object
var message = {


};

console.log('Sending Mail');
transporter.sendMail(message, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error occurred');
        console.log(error.message);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Message sent successfully!');
    console.log('Server responded with "%s"', info.response);
});
```

So again i want to be able to call the `'sending email'` method in this `full.js` file in my `$scope`..

As you can guess my misunderstanding of the server/client side logic holds me back to do or ask the right questions, but thx for you patience ;)

my data structure looks like :
client side = `root/app/js/` 
(where i have service.js and controllers.js).
Server side? `root/node-modules/nodemailer/`
 (as on github)

Comment: Go through this tutorials http://documentup.com/andris9/nodemailer/

Comment: hi, thx for answer. I have seen this tutorial, it's also posted on the github page. I manage to get Nodemailer working, pretty simple it is true. But i still have the problem of adapting it in a AngularJS's service using $http :(