# Angular JS with express contact form returning 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, forms, express

I'm trying to create a contact form to send an email with a message.

I'm quite new to Angular Express Node

This is the controller code:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name exampleApp.controller:ContactUsCtrl
 * @description
 * # ContactUsCtrl
 * Controller of the exampleApp
 */
angular.module('exampleApp')
.controller('ContactUsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$animate', function($scope, $http, $animate) {

  var self = this;
  self.sendMail = sendMail;

  function sendMail () {

    var req = {
     method: 'POST',
     url: '/contact_us',
     headers: {
       'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
     },
     data: 
      { 
        contactName : this.contactName,
        contactEmail : this.contactEmail,
        contactMsg : this.contactMsg
      }
    }

    $http(req).
      success(function (data, status, headers, config){
        console.log('success');
      }).
      error(function (data, status, headers, config){
        console.log('error');
      });

      console.log(req);

  };

}]);
```

This is my App.js

```
var subdomain = require("express-subdomain");
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

//Example Admin page
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('admin.html');
});

app.use(subdomain('admin', router));

//Config
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app');
app.use(morgan("combined"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

//Example client page
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('index.html');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

When ever I submit the form I get an error with the following message:
`POST http://localhost:5000/contact_us 404 (Not Found)`

What do else do I need to make a contact form work on AngularJS?

**edit**

these are my routes:

```
'use strict';

var xhrDelay = 1200;

angular.module('exampleApp', ['angularSpinner', 'ui.router', 'angular-ui-view-spinner'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $scope) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl as mc'
        // homepage: 'fixed'
      })
      .state('contact_us', {
        url: '/contact_us',
        templateUrl: 'views/contact_us.html',
        controller: 'ContactUsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'cu'
      });
  }]);
```

**solution**

I added this code in app.js (server code):

```
app.post('/contact_us',function(req,res){
  //Your NodeMailer logic comes here
  exports.sendMail = function(req, res) {

    var data = req.body;

    transporter.sendMail({
      from: data.contactEmail,
      to: 'jane@email.com',
      subject: 'Message from ' + data.contactName,
      text: data.contactMsg
    });

    res.json(data);
    };
});
```

source: [Sending AngularJS form to NodeMailer to send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614635/sending-angularjs-form-to-nodemailer-to-send-email)

with this, I no longer get the 404 error.

Comment: There is no ``app.post('/contact_us')`` route in your Express code. http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.post.method I suggest you to read the "Getting started" and "Guide" before going forward - http://expressjs.com/

Comment: I edited the question with my routes, I added that `app.post` in the express code but still the same error.

Comment: The routes are Angular front-end routes. You need to add the Express which is still missing, at least in your sample code right now. Add it right after the ``app.get('/'... `` definition. I am not going to post a code sample, as you NEED to read the documentation and understand how it all comes together or you'll hit a wall of what you are able to accomplish.

Comment: ok, I think I got it working, will edit the question

Comment: OK, good! You can just close the question now or accept any answers if you feel like it. So that it is not in the unanswered list in the SO. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code in app.js (server code):

```
app.post('/contact_us',function(req,res){
  //Your NodeMailer logic comes here
  exports.sendMail = function(req, res) {

    var data = req.body;

    transporter.sendMail({
      from: data.contactEmail,
      to: 'jane@email.com',
      subject: 'Message from ' + data.contactName,
      text: data.contactMsg
    });

    res.json(data);
    };
});
```

source: [Sending AngularJS form to NodeMailer to send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614635/sending-angularjs-form-to-nodemailer-to-send-email)

with this, I no longer get the 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

You need a '/contact_us' route in your App.js.

Comment: I've edited the question with my routes, I'm not sure where to put the `/contact_us` since I already have that one defined.